# how to use sed to replace matched with a list

Tags: linux, sed

I want to replace text files using sed but with a sequence.

example.txt：

```
1. 2000000
2. 2000000
3. 2000000
4. 2000000
```

I want a result like：

```
1. 2000000
2. 1900000
3. 1800000
4. 1700000
```

I have this dirty way:

```
for i in {2000000..1700000..-100000}; do sed -i -e "0,/2000000/! {0,/2000000/ s/2000000/$i/}" example.txt; done
```

Any better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk might be easier:

```
awk '{sub("2000000",2000000-(100000*c++))}1' file
```

The counter `c` isn't define for the first line and so number doesn't change. On the next line the counter is increase and the value is decreased.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. Is there a more general way for the list have different interval e.g. [5,4,3,1]?

Comment: @user2039439 I guess you mean to have the counter a non linear value. In that case you would assign the counter values into an array and iterate of it. If that's the direction you want to go and have difficulties with please ask another question.

Comment: I did it with your help @oliv. Thanks. Hope to help others `awk '/2000000/{sub("2000000",2000000-100000*c++)}1' Book1.csv | sed 's/200000$/250000/g'`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the second field with a number which decrements by 10,000 from the value on the first line, try

```
awk 'NR == 1 { value = $2 }
    NR > 1 { value -= 10000; $2 = value }
    1' file >newfile
```

Some variants of Awk have an `--inplace` option or similar which allows you to write the results back to the input file directly.

Refactoring this into a `sed` script is pretty pointless and speculative, but if you know the upper bounds of how many lines you expect in the file, you could generate a `sed` script like

```
2s/[1-9][0-9]*$/1900000/
3s/[1-9][0-9]*$/1800000/
4s/[1-9][0-9]*$/1700000/
:
```

for as many lines as necessary, then just run `sed` once with this script as its input.  If you are on Linux, you should be able to pipe the script into `sed`'s standard input:

```
for ((i=1900000, j=2; i>0; i-= 10000, j++)); do
    printf '%is/[1-9][0-9]*$/%i\n' "$j" "$i"
done |
sed -i -f - example.txt
```